# Why is Bugs Bunny's first name "Bugs"?

Tags: character, looney-tunes

As per Wikipedia Bugs Bunny was created in 1940 by Leon Schlesinger Productions (later Warner Bros. Cartoons).

So does any one know why his first name is **"BUGS"?**

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are several possible [explanations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Development_of_Bugs_Bunny):

> Several published first person accounts, encyclopedic references, and
>   Warner Bros.' own published material describe the inception of the
>   name and of the character. A model sheet by Charlie Thorson describes
>   this prototype character as "Bugs' Bunny" (note the apostrophe) but in
>   most of the cartoons the character is unnamed.
>
> Virgil Ross, the animator for A Wild Hare describes how the character
>   came to be named in the interview published by Animato! magazine. Mel
>   Blanc often told the story of the creation of the character and its
>   name. He suggested that the character be named after the character's
>   initial director, Ben "Bugs" Hardaway. Blanc's own book, That's Not
>   All Folks published by Warner Books in 1989, describes the "tough
>   little stinker" that was the eventual version of the redesigned
>   character as directed by Tex Avery.
>
> Warner Brothers' own published descriptions of the creation of the
>   character's name can be found in Animation Magazine published in 1990.
>   Therein it is described that the Hardaway unit's model sheet came to
>   be known by fellow animators as "Bugs' Bunny".
>
> A Wild Hare (July 27, 1940) was the debut of Bugs Bunny as we know him
>   today. (...) The cartoon was so successful that WB decided to keep him
>   on as a recurring character, eventually becoming the studio's most
>   popular cartoon character. The character's name, previously only used
>   on model sheets, became the official all-purpose name as well, with
>   one modification: the apostrophe was dropped from his first name (now
>   pronounced "bugs" rather than "bugs-es"). A title card saying
>   "featuring Bugs Bunny" was slapped onto Elmer's Pet Rabbit after
>   initial production of that cartoon wrapped up, though that cartoon had
>   the rabbit carry the pre-Wild Hare characteristics.